# mysqlbackup 8.0.16 does not recognise --defaults-extra-file option

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-8.0

**OS-RHEL 7.4**

**MySQL Server- 8.0.16 commercial (trial)**

**defaults-file=/mysql_data/config/options.cnf**

**defaults-extra-file=/mysql_data/config/extra_options.cnf**

```
[root@exampledb01 logical_backup]# ls -l /mysql_data/config/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1020 Jul 25 15:36 extra_options.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 6164 Jul 25 16:25 options.cnf
```

I am using **mysqlbackup 8.0.16-commercial (trial version)** for backing up the 
databases in my environment.

I have been successfully using the option (**--defaults-extra-file**)  with **mysqldump** program from community and commercial versions 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0. I save mysql user names and passwords (and other login information in the file). When I tried to use the same with **mysqlbackup**, it does not recognise the option.

```
[root@exampledb01 logical_backup]# mysqlbackup --defaults-extra-file=/mysql_data/config/extra_options.cnf --backup-dir=/mysql_backup/physical_backup/full_backups/2019-07-21 --with-timestamp backup-and-apply-log

MySQL Enterprise Backup  Ver 8.0.16-commercial for linux-glibc2.12 on x86_64 (MySQL Enterprise - Commercial)
Copyright (c) 2003, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Starting with following command line ...
 mysqlbackup --defaults-extra-file=/mysql_data/config/extra_options.cnf 
        --backup-dir=/mysql_backup/physical_backup/full_backups/2019-07-21 
        --with-timestamp backup-and-apply-log 

MAIN: [ERROR] unknown option '--~'.

mysqlbackup exit code: 7, Invalid Argument

mysqlbackup failed with errors!
```

The option **defaults-file** is very happily accepted by the **mysqlbackup** program, however, it doesn't do so for **--defaults-extra-file** option.

The mysqlbackup command reference mentions that the option **--defaults-extra-file** is acceptable for the program.

I have searched the documentation and googled about it but there is not much I could find. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/standard-options.html

I can proceed with the --defaults-file option in my backup script but I am not sure what's wrong with the --defaults-extra-file option.

Comment: I am not sure this is really a question-- if you are sure this is a defect, you should report it to the bug tracker and either it should documented or fixed: https://bugs.mysql.com

Comment: Well, I am not sure if it's a defect. This indeed is a question. May be somewhere down the line I am missing something. That is the reason I intend to seek help from experts instead of directly jumping to the conclusion that it's a bug.

Comment: Bug #96362 -- I have posted it as a bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96362&thanks=4